# SQL Server Configuration Manager not showing the details

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms, ssas

When I am opening the SQL Server Configuration Manager, the details are not being shown. I am only seeing the attached screenshot above.

[image: SQL Server Configuration Manager]

And also when I opened `services.msc`, I am seeing multiple instances of SQL Server, SQL Server Agent, SQL Server Analysis Services and SQL Server Integration Services.

I am using the SQL Server instance named `SQL_DEVELOPER` only. I need the multiple instances to be removed.

SSAS is working fine with `SQL_DEVELOPER` instance, but with same instance the SSIS is not working.

[image]

Also I am also facing issue to start the SQL Server Integration Services in `services.msc`.

[image]

Comment: SSIS is a shared component. You cannot have multiple instances of the same SSIS version installed. If your `SQL_DEVLOPER` named instance hosts the SSISDB catalog, connect to the `LENOVA\SQL_DEVLOPER` database engine (not Integration Services) and expand the Integration Services Catalogs node under Object Explorer. If you don't have a catalog yet, right-click on that node and select `Create Catalog...`.

Comment: For the snap-in problem, you might try repairing shared features.

Comment: @DanGuzman for the SQL Server Configuration Manager not showing the details I executed the setup of SQL server and entered the Repair section and resolved issue and details started to show in the SQL Server Configuration Manager..and for multi-instance SSIS issue I followed the solution given by : http://shahfaisalmuhammed.blogspot.com/2011/09/managing-multiple-instances-of-sql.html#:~:text=SSIS%20service%20does%20not%20support,ini.&text=Now%20when%20you%20connect%20to,just%20use%20the%20server%20name ..Was able to connect to SSIS after that..thank you.